# How do I make this compact, efficient and readable?

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing

So I have a bit of code that parses a chunk of a mathematical expression between operators. For instance, the mathematical expression

```
x^2+5.09*x+(123.1+x)
```

looks like

```
[expr_0][op_1][expr_1][op_2][expr_2][op_3][expr_3]
```

where

```
expr_0 = 'x'
op_1 = '^'
expr_1 = '2'
op_2 = '+'
expr_2 = '5.09'
op_3 = '*'
expr_3 = 'x'
op_4 = '+'
expr_4 = '123.1+x'
```

In my algorithm there comes a point where the current character in math function string is expected to be the beginning of an expression (one of `expr_0`, `expr_1`, `expr_2` or `expr_3` above) I need to put that expression in a string and advance the pointer to the current character to one beyond the expression. An expression will either be `'x'`, a number (e.g. '`5.09'`) or an expression in parenthesis.

My function for what is described in the above paragraph looks like

```
node * getNextExpression ( char ** begptr )
{
    // begptr: pointer to the character at the beginning of the expression

    node * result;

    if (**begptr == 'x') // next expression is the variable 'x'
    {
        result = malloc(sizeof(node));
        result->fx = "x"; result->gx = NULL; result->op = NULL; result->hx = NULL;
    }
    else if ((**begptr >= '0' && **begptr  <= '9') || **begptr== '.') // next expression is a number
    {
        int foundPeriod = 0;
        char * cpy = *begptr;
        do
        {
            if (**begptr == '.')
            {
                if (foundPeriod == 0) foundPeriod = 1;
                else break;
            }
            ++*begptr;
        } while ((**begptr >= '0' && **begptr  <= '9') || **begptr == '.');
        long n = *begptr - cpy;
        char * numstr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 1));
        numstr[n] = '\0';
        for (long k = 0; k < n; ++k) numstr[k] = *cpy++;
        result->fx = numstr; result->gx = NULL; result->op = NULL; result->hx = NULL;
    }
    else if (**begptr == '(') // next expression is enclosed in parantheses
    {
        // .... haven't got this down yet
    }
    else
    {
        result = NULL;
    }
    return result;
}
```

which is a complete mess and possibly wrong. Is there a more compact procedure for getting a number into a string `numstr`, meanwhile advancing the pointer `*begptr`?

For reference, a `node` is

```
typedef struct node
{
    char * fx; // function
    struct node * gx; // left-hand side
    char * op; // operator
    struct node * hx; // right-hand side
} node;
```

Comment: First off you could get rid of the entire `else if` tree stuff by immediately using `return result;` whenever you have a positive match for the next part.

Comment: This type of problem has well known tested solutions (Google ANTLR for example), or you could replace the entire thing with a nice regex to do the work for you.

Comment: "How do I make this compact, efficient and readable?" Use a scanner generator like flex. I assume that this question is in aid of a homework assignment and flex is not a possibility, but in any other context, there is no reason whatsoever to handroll a lexical analyser.

Comment: @rici Yes educational reasons are the only justification, and I would move all declarations to the begining of the block where they're valid, because that affects readability. And don't use `sizeof(char)` since there is no way that it will not be `1`.

Comment: @iharob: (caution, rant follows): We can agree to disagree about declarations. I think OP has already achieved the key educational outcome, which is to learn that hand-written scanners are ugly and bug-ridden. :) Making students hand-write scanners is a form of academic sadism, which would be similar to forcing them to write out optimised for loops in x86 machine language in order to "learn how loops work" (in case anyone still does that). /rant

Comment: @rici, I totally aggree with you.

Comment: @iharob: also use `strcpy` (or better yet, `strdup`) and define a functional interface for creating nodes. And a large etc. But no matter how you cut it, writing out dfas is not fun.

Comment: @rici: If teaching the principles of a Finite State Machine, then I would argue that hand-rolling a scanner **might** be a suitable exercise for the students. Otherwise I agree with you entirely. It seems clear in this instance that the principles of FSM have not yet been introduced to the OP.

Comment: Uh... am I the only one all for hand-written scanners since you can have finer grained error messages?

Comment: @qix: I've seen the argument that hand-built *parsers* produce better error messages (or more easily produce better error messages), and that's certainly a consideration, but a scanner? You have a pointer to an example?